# Community Poll - Reading Seminar - Pilot Experiment

Tags: discussion, suggestions, site-promotion, community-events

[Keshav Srinivasan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan), one of the power users of our Stack Exchange has kindly agreed to lead a reading seminar. The seminar entails, upon the selection of a common text, curated reading & discussion of selected text in regular intervals. The discussion will be led & moderated by Keshav via scheduled chat event.

Expect detailed and multi-faceted discussions with the aims to collect & boost the spirit of enquiry which the StackExchange has been known for. Participants will be directly requried to engage in coming up with focused, quality questions of depth in the flavour that the site has come to experience as well as Summary Posts in the form of Q&A posts - which are based upon a natural extension of the readings and discussions.

Given this context, this poll is intended to gauge the community interest in such a pilot venture by directly asking for suggestions of the text that **you** would like to see. Without further ado, please vote on the text of your choice and **leave a comment** so that we can know that you're interested.

**NOTE**: If the text you are interested in is not given as an answer, please feel free to add it(One text per answer).

Comment: JMO, Reading seminar may not be good idea. Interpretation plays a major role in Hindu Scriptures. Moreover, Shruti (Vedas) should be read under guidance of Guru. Except very few users here, most of them are reading Scriptures  on their own (including me :Smriti and Puranas, and i didn't read Vedas and Upanishads). So, i think this is comparatively not useful. (Btw, i don't want to offend Keshav). Many users may feel like this. JMO.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Leaving aside the fact that we will not be reading Shruti Texts in this venture, how does reading other scriptures like smriti, purana & commentaries on **one's own** ensure more suitable interpretation than reading as a group? Even so, in this proposed group reading, people are encouraged to come up with reasons for their point of view ensuring that everyone benefits from that perspective - this adds more not less to the process of reading a scripture. Moderation doesn't imply stultification of a perspective - Stack Exchange itself being a prime example of that philosophy.

Comment: "Moderation doesn't imply stultification of a perspective - Stack Exchange itself being a prime example of that philosophy." what moderation? how is it related to my above statement?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Moderation of reading discussions or the idea of moderated group discussion of a text in general. It is meant as a summary of my comment in a single statement, which to reiterate, is that reading on one's own is not always the final word, moderated discussions can help broaden one's perspective as well as sharpen it.

Answer (score 5):

Shabara's Bhashya on Jaimini's Purva Mimamsa Sutras.

Comment: @All who voted for above, please add your names as comment so we can start sessions.

Comment: I'm interested in reading Jaimini's Purva Mimansa Sutras; looking for Sanskrit-Hindi book if available.

Comment: @Pandya Good idea, that way we can get more perspective. I think we can start this proper from the month of December.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I am also interested. But I will be in India in December.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not interested in participating.

Answer (score 1):

RamanujAcharya's SriBhashya on Vyasa's Brahma Sutras.